# Problems with creating projects with bitnami gitlab

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I have installed bitnami gitlab 7.6.2. I have installed it in my window server via virtual box. I have successfully installed it but its not allowing me to create any new project. Whenever  I am trying to create a new project I get the follows:

Sidekiq log:

```
/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416:in `block in task'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13:in `block in create'

2015-02-12T04:05:13Z 3366 TID-ormzo02mo Devise::Async::Backend::Sidekiq JID-c258018705e11825d7ecafad INFO: fail: 1.741 sec

2015-02-12T04:05:13Z 3366 TID-ormzo02mo WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"mailer", "class"=>"Devise::Async::Backend::Sidekiq", "args"=>["confirmation_instructions", "User", "1", "eX85zvqyU9y2E6PU8dKL", {}], "jid"=>"c258018705e11825d7ecafad", "enqueued_at"=>1423212629.0285604, "error_message"=>"hostname \"localhost\" does not match the server certificate", "error_class"=>"OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError", "failed_at"=>1423212773.4829438, "retry_count"=>15, "retried_at"=>1423713913.6416764}

2015-02-12T04:05:13Z 3366 TID-ormzo02mo WARN: hostname "localhost" does not match the server certificate

2015-02-12T04:05:13Z 3366 TID-ormzo02mo WARN: /opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb:178:in `post_connection_check'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:588:in `tlsconnect'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:563:in `do_start'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:527:in `block in deliver_mail'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:525:in `deliver_mail'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-async-0.9.0/lib/devise/async/backend/base.rb:16:in `perform'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:49:in `block (3 levels) in process'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122:in `call'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122:in `block in invoke'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:62:in `call'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:22:in `with_context'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `call'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `invoke'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in process'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:108:in `stats'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:47:in `block in process'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:86:in `do_defer'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.8/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:37:in `process'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `public_send'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `dispatch'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322:in `block in handle_message'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416:in `block in task'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'

/opt/gitlab-7.6.2-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13:in `block in create'
```

Similarly my production log is

```
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3rpA5OaE7jF16Wk/RGH+CtTLG/glgGbZGS+ViptXg0c=", "project"=>{"name"=>"test", "namespace_id"=>"3", "path"=>"", "import_url"=>"", "description"=>"", "visibility_level"=>"0"}}

Completed 200 OK in 1236ms (Views: 89.7ms | ActiveRecord: 268.3ms)

Started GET "/admin" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:10 +0545

Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML

Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 127.2ms | ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)

Started GET "/admin/background_jobs" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:12 +0545

Processing by Admin::BackgroundJobsController#show as HTML

Completed 200 OK in 235ms (Views: 55.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:12 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/javascripts/locales/jquery.timeago.en.js" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:12 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/javascripts/dashboard.js" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:12 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/javascripts/application.js" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:12 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/stylesheets/application.css" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:12 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:13 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/images/status-sd8051fd480.png" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:13 +0545

Started GET "/admin/logs" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:14 +0545

Processing by Admin::LogsController#show as HTML

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/dashboard/stats" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:15 +0545

Completed 200 OK in 2340ms (Views: 2319.2ms | ActiveRecord: 9.4ms)

Started GET "/admin/logs" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:51:17 +0545

Processing by Admin::LogsController#show as HTML

Completed 200 OK in 408ms (Views: 398.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)

Started GET "/admin/projects" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:12 +0545

Processing by Admin::ProjectsController#index as HTML

Completed 200 OK in 437ms (Views: 362.6ms | ActiveRecord: 64.1ms)

Started GET "/projects/new" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:14 +0545

Processing by ProjectsController#new as HTML

Completed 200 OK in 456ms (Views: 365.9ms | ActiveRecord: 25.9ms)

Started POST "/projects" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:21 +0545

Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3rpA5OaE7jF16Wk/RGH+CtTLG/glgGbZGS+ViptXg0c=", "project"=>{"name"=>"test", "namespace_id"=>"3", "path"=>"", "import_url"=>"", "description"=>"adsfsadf", "visibility_level"=>"0"}}

Completed 200 OK in 908ms (Views: 297.7ms | ActiveRecord: 199.0ms)

Started GET "/admin" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:24 +0545

Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML

Completed 200 OK in 254ms (Views: 177.2ms | ActiveRecord: 69.1ms)

Started GET "/admin/background_jobs" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:27 +0545

Processing by Admin::BackgroundJobsController#show as HTML

Completed 200 OK in 125ms (Views: 49.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:27 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/stylesheets/application.css" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:27 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/javascripts/application.js" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:27 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:27 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/javascripts/dashboard.js" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:27 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/javascripts/locales/jquery.timeago.en.js" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:27 +0545

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/images/status-sd8051fd480.png" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:27 +0545

Started GET "/admin/logs" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:29 +0545

Processing by Admin::LogsController#show as HTML

Started GET "/admin/sidekiq/dashboard/stats" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:52:29 +0545

Completed 200 OK in 1098ms (Views: 1082.7ms | ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)

Started GET "/admin/logs" for 10.10.10.105 at 2015-02-12 09:55:56 +0545

Processing by Admin::LogsController#show as HTML
```

My bitnami gitlab is installed in opt. I dont know what exactly is the problem. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Set in your `vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

`gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false`
`gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'`